# Allow read only access to Mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I would like team leaders read-only access to all team member mailboxes. This permissions must apply to all folders and inherit to new folders.

I would like to achieve this without modifying permissions from the client application.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not correct (even though it comes from Technet - go figure), but [Exfolders](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-RTM-ExFolders-c76c3649), formerly known as PFDAVAdmin, does provide this functionality.

<strike>With PowerShell, it's pretty easy.</strike>

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124097.aspx

This example grants Ayla Kol read permission to Tony Smith's mailbox.

```
 Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Tony Smith" -User "Ayla Kol" -AccessRights ReadPermission
```

You can either write a little script to find team leaders and their team members to feed into that cmdlet, or if your environment's a small one, you could always just do it manually.

Comment: I had been using this command. It hadn't worked. I also can't seem to find a description of the different access rights; doesn't 'readpermission' allow reading of permissions? Or is it the read permission.

Comment: Yes. Confirmed as suspected.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct.  Have you tried ExFolders? (The 2010 version of PFDAVAdmin) http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-RTM-ExFolders-c76c3649

Comment: I haven't. I will give it a try right now. Many thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry I haven't accepted this answer yet. I have been distracted with other problems. I hope to try again soon. At any rate perhaps a second answer should be submitted for exfolders as the answer submited is not correct.